# Search a PHP string for whitespace after a particular character

Tags: php, string, substring

This is my string :

```
$string = '@ somebody and some other stuff';
```

How could I detect the whitespace after the @ character?

If I find the match I would like to do something with original string.

```
$string2 = '@ ';
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Do you want to detect whether your string has the sequence `@ ` somewhere or not? What should the result be if there is no white space after the `@`? What should be the result when there is no `@`? What if there are multiple of them in the string?

Comment: I was wondering the same

Comment: Sorry I thought it was pretty clear. I want to detect if the @ is followed by whitespace in a string and then assign '@ ' to  new variable

Comment: And if not? And if multiple? ...

Comment: To add, I already have logic set up to detect characters directly after the @ symbol. But the issue I'm having is that if somebody writes '@ something' it's returning 'Array' instead of the @ symbol. The rest of the code creating the array based on the characters directly after the @. When there is white space it's obviously not working properly.

Comment: When you look at the different answers already given, which all understand your question differently, it should ring a bell, that you might not be that clear... :-)

Comment: I have the rest of it working fine, multiple instances etc, it's just the whitespace entries that are bombing it out

Comment: So, you don't want to get `@ ` like your wrote. You want to **remove** the space that is bothering you. Right?

Comment: No I don't, I need to keep the whitespace so I can set it to a variable which will bypass the function that prints the array derived from correctly formatted @somethings

Comment: @Ljubisa has given me the solution I need below. Again, sorry if I wasn't clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to find `@` and remove space?

```
$string = str_replace("@ ", "@", $string);
```

**EDIT**
You want this [PHP source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// Note our use of ===.  Simply == would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
?>
```

Comment: No I don't want to remove the whitespace, I want to keep it and assign both the @ and the white space after it to a new variable

Comment: @Grant this is what you want I just added it.. So you can check for it and IF it exists do stuff with the string.. Good luck

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I needed. Sorry If I wasn't clearer in my question and thanks man ;)

Comment: You are welcome @Grant please do accept the answer if you agree with it. Best of luck with your project. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace('/@ (.*)/', '@ ', $string);
```